# How to check for each same value we have same unique id in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with 3 left join gives me below mentioned output:

```
T2      ID        value1     Type     value2       frq        Value3
L-1     AB-12     ARTY55A    X        [Null]       8          ARTY55A
L-1     AB-12     ARTy55A    X        [Null]       7          BHyT78B
L-2     AB-21     VGTY25E    Y        VGTY25E      8          VGTY25E
L-3     AB-14     [Null]     Z        FRTE20E      8          FRTE20E
L-5     AB-18     AURT10E    X        [Null]       8          AURT10E
L-5     AB-18     AURT10E    X        [Null]       7          AERT10E
L-6     AB-18     AURT10E    X        [Null]       8          AURT10E
```

Now i want to check count that for same `Value3` with `Type`=X having `frq` 8, have the same unique `ID` with Distinct count 1.

And for all the same `Value2` with `Type`!=X have the same unique `ID` with Distinct count 1. (Here we don't check frq)

Expected Result:

```
Value3   Value3_count     ID_count Value2   Value2_count   ID
ARTY55A  1                1        VGTY25E  1              1
AURT10E  2                1        [Null]   [Null]         [Null]
```

Comment: show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Updated the question with example.

Comment: It is hardly possible to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jacobian I just want to know that for each unique `Value3` and `Value2` we have a unique `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a group by  and count

```
  select t.Value3, count(*)
  from (  select a.Value3 from table1 left join..... ) t 
      where Type = 'X'
      and frq = 8
  group by t.Value3
```

and

```
  select t.Value2, count(*)
  from ( select a.Value3 from table1 left join..... ) t 
      where Type != 'X'
  group by t.Value2
```

Comment: I just need to pass my query like: `select a.Value3 from table1 left join.....` in to this line `from (  my query with 3 left join ) t`

Comment: answer  updated .. with your select a.Value3 from table1 left join.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select Value3, count(*) as Value3_count, count(distinct ID) as ID_count
from (  my query with 3 left join ) t
where Type = 'X' and frq = 8
group by Value3;

select Value2, count(*) as Value2_count, count(distinct ID) as ID_count
from (  my query with 3 left join ) t
where Type != 'X'
group by Value2;
```